# Blocking recv() vs fcntl()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I am using `recv()` to read data from a socket and `fcntl()` to set the socket blocking/non-blocking. My question is: If I called `recv()` (blocking) and I call `fcntl()` from another thread and set the socket non-blocking, will the currently running `recv()` return or the effect of `fcntl()` will only take place after the blocking `recv()` returns and I call it again?

Comment: Try it out. It is strange that you want a socket to be both blocking and non-blocking, and have a another thread diddle with the status.  On linux, I would set the socket non-blocking on creation with socket() on client, and accept4() on server.

Comment: Are you just trying to asynchronously wake a thread blocked on a `recv` call?  If so, there's probably a better/safer way to do it even if `fcntl` yields the desired result.  For example, use `poll` to block on the external `recv` socket *or* an internal-only socket used just for intra-process notifications.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland This is exactly what I was planning on doing but since it wouldn't even work (according to EJP's answer), I will look into your ideas. Thanks!

Comment: The simplest solution is just calling `poll` (or `select` or `epoll_wait`) with a timeout, followed by checking a flag that gets set by other threads.  Obviously there is some CPU cycle wasting from waking when you don't need to.  Beyond that, try either an [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html),  [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), or [socketpair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) in order from lowest to highest flexibility and in turn resource overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't affect the current receive operation.

Strange thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wanted to wake up the blocking thread using this method, but I guess I will look into other options.

Comment: @BertalanRadostyan: "*I wanted to wake up the blocking thread*" Just send the thread a signal (make sure `SA_RESTART` isn't  the signal handler).